# (Lua) Is there a way to execute code and run a function if there is an error?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to execute a function if there is an error when executing another block of code

Here's what I mean:

In Javascript, there is a function called `try` and `catch`, where you place code in `try` and `catch` executes if there is an error

Here it is in action:

```js
try {
  throw("Error")
} catch (error) {
  console.log("there was an error: " + error)
}
```

So how would I do this in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Lua, you need to create a function, and then use a function called `pcall()` that will analyze if at any point in the function it will return an error. This is the Lua's `Try-Catch`

example:

```lua
function test()
     print("Hello World")
end

if not pcall(test) then -- if there is an error within the function then .....
       print("ERROR")
else
      print("no errors")
end
```